# How to set my own icon for markers in clusterer in Google Maps

Tags: android, google-maps, markerclusterer

I'm using GoogleMaps clustering. I have 4 different types of markers, each extends from one abstract class, each has its owm icon and it defined in MarkerOptions field. I use ClusterManager for this abstract class.
When I just use

```
//marker is instance of one of extended classes and has abstract class type
clusterManager.addItem(marker);
```

After clustering it sets icon to default. How I can fix this? I was trying to use something like this:

```
//marker is abstract marker, getMarker returns the MarkerOptions of this marker
clusterManager.getMarkerCollection().addMarker(marker.getMarker());
```

but it doesn't work too, marker is printed with needed icon on map, but without clustering.

Should I create create some method in my abstract class or there are some way to do this extending from DefaultClusterRenderer? I haven't found some information about it using Google or learning google maps lib.

Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 29, accepted):

So, it was my foolish. Again, it shows, that I should pay more attention, studying library. If somebody is interested in answer, here it is: 
I was right supposing, that I need to override some method in DefaultClusterRenderer. So, the full way:
Create own class and extend it from DefaultClusterRenderer:

```
public class OwnIconRendered extends DefaultClusterRenderer<AbstractMarker>
```

Then override method **onBeforeClusterItemRendered**:

```
@Override
protected void onBeforeClusterItemRendered(AbstractMarker item,
        MarkerOptions markerOptions) {
    markerOptions.icon(item.getMarker().getIcon());
}
```

The way is rather simple, but it seems to me, that clustering started to work slower. So, that's enough.

Comment: I think it's too late, but for the future you can take a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27745299/how-to-add-title-snippet-and-icon-to-clusteritem/27745681#27745681

Comment: in my case I had to call `super().onBeforeClustererItemRendered`

Comment: Hey! Late on this. But what was the impact on clustering after adding custom icons? How much slower? Could you share some numbers? I am also working on similar problem, and I want to get some idea of how much performance hit does it take, before I start.
@VasilovArtur