# Android cluster map change marker

Tags: java, android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I was having some troubles when trying to customize the clsutered markers on Google Map. I am using Google Map Android API Library and reference from [GoogleMap Documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/utility/marker-clustering). Here are my codes:

```
private void setUpClusterer() {
    googleBasemap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(
            1.379348, 103.849876), 11.0f));
    mClusterManager = new ClusterManager<EventClusterItem>(this,
            googleBasemap);
    googleBasemap.setOnCameraChangeListener(mClusterManager);
    googleBasemap.setOnMarkerClickListener(mClusterManager);
    addItems();
}

private void addItems() {
    for (int i = 0; i < convertedGeomList.size(); i++) {
        EventClusterItem offsetItem = new EventClusterItem(convertedGeomList.get(i)
                .getY(), convertedGeomList.get(i).getX());
        mClusterManager.addItem(offsetItem);
    }
}
```

And my EventClusterItem class:

```
public class EventClusterItem implements ClusterItem {
private final LatLng mPosition;

public EventClusterItem(double lat, double lng) {
    mPosition = new LatLng(lat, lng);
}

public LatLng getPosition() {
    return mPosition;
}
}
```

So basically with these codes, it only shows up a red color marker onto the map. I wonder how can I customize the marker with my own image. I know you can do this to customize the marker on the map:

```
Marker melbourne = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                      .position(MELBOURNE)
                      .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_AZURE)));
```

But I not sure how to implement it in this case. Any guides?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Any guides? I am stuck

Answer (score 4):

Use answers from these posts:

[How to set my own icon for markers in clusterer in Google Maps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23658561/how-to-set-my-own-icon-for-markers-in-clusterer-in-google-maps)

[How to add title, snippet and icon to ClusterItem?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27745299/how-to-add-title-snippet-and-icon-to-clusteritem/27745681#27745681)

There is no any guide about this API. You should find the code for this library and try to understand it - it is easy, the code is perfect (but a little bit slow in fact).