# Android - How To Change 'Pin' Google Maps Clustering

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-markers, markerclusterer

I want to change the default `pin`on `clustering` `google-maps` with my own `icon`, I need help to solve that. This is my MainActivity.class

```
package com.example.bimaaldi.mapss;

import android.Manifest;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.BitmapDescriptorFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;
import com.google.maps.android.clustering.ClusterManager;

public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    private GoogleMap mMap;
    private ClusterManager<MyItem> mClusterManager;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
        // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        setUpMapIfNeeded();
    }

    private void setUpMapIfNeeded() {
        if (mMap == null) {
            mMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))
                    .getMap();

        }
    }


    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;

        LatLng zoom = new LatLng(-7.966658, 112.631923);

        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(zoom, 13));
        mClusterManager = new ClusterManager <MyItem>(this, mMap);
        mMap.setOnCameraChangeListener(mClusterManager);
        mMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(mClusterManager);

        addItems();

        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // TODO: Consider calling
            //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
            // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
            //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
            //                                          int[] grantResults)
            // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
            // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
            return;
        }
        mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
    }
    private void addItems(){

        mClusterManager.addItem(new MyItem(-7.976557,112.628464));
                mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                        .title("Pia Cap Mangkok")
                        .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.kue)));

        mClusterManager.addItem(new MyItem(-7.959904, 112.632161));
        mClusterManager.addItem(new MyItem(-7.966447, 112.633693));
        mClusterManager.addItem(new MyItem(-7.974462, 112.636852));
        mClusterManager.addItem(new MyItem(-7.952476, 112.618387));
        mClusterManager.addItem(new MyItem(-7.985999, 112.638294));
        mClusterManager.addItem(new MyItem(-7.982339, 112.634663));
        mClusterManager.addItem(new MyItem(-7.976261, 112.617243));
        mClusterManager.addItem(new MyItem(-7.975363, 112.626559));
        mClusterManager.addItem(new MyItem(-7.974657, 112.623750));
    }
}
```

This is my MyItem.class

```
public class MyItem implements ClusterItem {
    private final LatLng mPosition;

    public MyItem(double lat, double lng) {
        mPosition = new LatLng(lat,lng);
    }

    @Override
    public LatLng getPosition() {
        return mPosition;
    }
}
```

What should I add to my code.
Thank you.

Comment: what to want to change Markers icon or the clusters icon?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27745681/5722385 this link might help you!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27745681/7316510 or http://stackoverflow.com/a/23684039/7316510 may help you!

Comment: markers icon. Thank you!